# After import csvkit, I have syntax error

Tags: csv, csvkit

I am beginner of python. I imported csvkit, and tried to convert an excel file to CSV file. But I get the syntax error.

Could anyone help me with that?

Thank you!

```
import csvkit

in2csv 2014.xlsx > 2014.csv
  File "<ipython-input-18-696ca5bd43c2>", line 1
    in2csv 2014.xlsx > 2014.csv
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

csvkit is a command line utility. It looks like you are trying to use in a python script.